# Trying to to give different "screens" in jpanel when changing comboBox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox, layout-manager

So im trying to creat a Jpanel with a comboBox at the top, with 2 options, when choose options you get different "screens" in the jpanel but the comboBox stays, i know how to create comboBox and ActionLister but my question is how do i change the screens? do put different panels in the jframe? any ideas?

Comment: what does you mean by screen ?

Comment: like a set of different options in the frame, screen is a pretty bad word to describe it :-)

Comment: You would use a CardLayout to swap JPanel "views" held in another JPanel.

Comment: JSE doesn't have such component other than JTabbedPan which allow you to put different panel with tabs to browse amon them. you can add your combobox action to select a tab with corresponding screen. Otherwise you need to write your own custom component with layout. Let us know a little more detail

Comment: @Sage: what are you talking about? Your comment above does not make sense. To the original poster, you might want to be careful with sage's advice. Again, a CardLayout would likely work just fine.

Comment: I just answered as much as i understood Gigala's question and i am pretty confused about the screen he mentioned. If he wants an option like navigation of different set of options like we do in a TextEditor JTabbedPan is a good choice. **I did mention about layout too. And i did ask him about more details!**, so beat some more sense in me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> im trying to create JPanel with a comboBox at the top, with 2 options, when choose options you get different "screens" in the jpanel but the comboBox stays

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example that does exactly what you want.

Comment: See also the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047101/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513).